# AngularJS object filter in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element which uses ng-options to iterate through jobPosting objects.  Each jobPosting object has a jobTitle, a recruiter, and multiple other things.  I want the jobTitle of each to show up as the selectable options in my select element.  As of now, I have that working, but I am having a problem with the filter.  I have:

```
<select ng-model="currentlySelectedJob"
ng-options="job as job.jobTitle for job in jobs | filter : {job.recruiter: currentRecruiter}">
</select>
```

The filter works in the sense that it filters, but it filters on everything inside the object.  I need it to only filter on the recruiter.  The user types in the name of a recruiter and it should only show job titles which have that name as the recruiter.  I am sorry if this question was already answered, but I looked at the available answers, and I didn't see anything I understood well enough to know whether or not it actually answered my question.  Thank you for any help.

P.S. if someone could also explain the purpose of using the "as" keyword in ng-options that would be helpful as well.  I have yet to find a time when I need to use it and I'm not sure what it does or why you would use it.

Comment: `filter : {recruiter: currentRecruiter}`

Comment: Well, that wasn't so bad!  It worked!  Thank you.  =)